# No Session found for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am trying to get the size of attendees (a list, which is a oneToMany in class Presentation)

Planning contains a OneToMany with the corresponding presentations

Every time i try to get the size of attendees it fails to lazy load them. I tried writing a query but it says that i can't use the fetch twice. Is there any good way to get the data i need?

There are a lot of discussions on the internet about this but none of them seem to solve my problem.

I am running on the latest version of hibernate (4.1.7.Final) and am using spring Release 3.2.3

Planning repo:

```
public interface PlanningRepository extends JpaRepository<Planning, Long>{

    @Query("select pl from Planning pl join fetch pl.presentations p join fetch p.attendees a where pl.id = ?1")
    Planning findOneById(Long id);
}
```

The relation in class Presentation:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "presentation_attendees",
     joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "presentation_id")},
     inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")})
private List<Student> attendees;
```

The relation in student:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "attendees")
private List<Presentation> presentationsAttending;
```

Where i call it in PlanningController:

```
Planning planning = planningRepository.findOneById(1L);                       


JSONArray pArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject planningJSON = new JSONObject();


//List<Presentation> presentations = (List<Presentation>)presentationRepository.findByPlanning(planning.getId());

for(Presentation p : planning.getPresentations()) 
{            
    sessionFactory.openSession();
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().begin();
    //i need the size of attendees
    presentationJSON.put("subscribers", p.getAttendees().size());
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    sessionFactory.close();
}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="school"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure the Planning record you retrieve has Presentations and Attendees?

Comment: yes it has 2 presentations and 1 of the presentations has 1 attendee.

Comment: If you dont use an OpenSessionInViewFilter or jpa equivalent your transaction is gone after you leave the find method (and the hibernate session is closed). So either use OSIV or you can use @Transactional on the .find() method and call .size() once there to fetch the list lazily.

Comment: i use OSIV now but it still doesn't work

Comment: I updated my original post with extra information

Comment: Where are your transaction boundaries?

Comment: I don't know why i have to use them, isn't it just a regular select statement that can be fetched from the jpaRepository inside spring

Comment: Any interaction to the database requires a transaction. If you havent explicitly created a transaction (either in code or using spring annotations), then a transaction will implicitly be created per interaction with the database. So the select statement will be executed in one transaction. When you later go to lazily fetch a field that was returned from that select, it will fail since there isnt a transaction associated with that entity in the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing List<> to Set<> on the ManyToMany and OneToMany relations

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose your Repository calls inside of a Service method.

Ex:-

```
PresentationService

@Transactional
public List<Long> getAttendeesCountForPlanning(Long planningId) {
    ... 
}
```

This must return the List of Presentation Attendees Count for each Planning Id. So this will be enclosed within a single transaction. For more information read this [post](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

Comment: This would give me a query for each presentation in a planning, resulting in a lot of queries. I need a way to have this in 1 query (which is possible with joins) however i cant find a good way.

Comment: Then if you can't accomplish this using @Query try writing a Specification or using QueryDSL. Check this post http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Answer (score 0):

Strange as it seems calling a transactional method in the method does not work. For example, see

```
@Service       
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{

    @Autowired
    MyDAO myDAO;


    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public MyObject method1(String param) {

        return MyObject myObject = myDAO.get(param);
    }       


    @Override
        //Won't work without the transactional annotation
    public MyObject method2() {

              return method1("bla");
    }       
}
```